# TwiML™ Voice: <Play> not playing google cloud storage url

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, twilio, flask-restful, twilio-twiml

I am trying to use Twilio Voice to play an mp3 file. The mp3 file is uploaded to GCS bucket and the url of the mp3 file is in the below given format:

https://storage.googleapis.com/project_name/folder_name/file_name.mp3

Below is the code snippet in python flask which is invoked using an hhtp call:

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def welcome():
    name = 'messi'
    url = GCSAgent().search_mp3_file(name)
    print(f'Logging url:{url}')
    response = VoiceResponse()
    response.play(url)
    print(response)
    return '200'
```

The value of `print(response)` is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Play>https://storage.googleapis.com/project_name/folder_name/file_name.mp3</Play></Response>
```

Below is the property of the mp3 file:
[image]

When i am picking up the call there is no mp3 file which is played but when I use the Say/Play widget and I give the above url, the mp3 is getting played. What is the issue with Twilio or there is something which I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, below is the code snippet:

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def welcome():
    name = 'messi'
    url = GCSAgent().search_mp3_file(name)
    print(f'Logging url:{url}')
    response = VoiceResponse()
    response.play(url)
    print(response)
    return str(response)
```

The only change we need to do is **return the response as string** instead of returning the status code.

So in Twilio what happens is, when you call the endpoint, the TwiML is returned which is then get processed. See the screen shot below for one of the call flows:

[image: Twilio Call Flow]

What Twilio does is, it gets the TwiML and then performs a GET request for the mp3 URL which is mentioned in the TwiML and then plays it but this will not happen if we return something apart from the response.

Comment: I am glad you found the solution. My guess is if you would have checked the Twilio logs for the prior unsuccessful calls it would have shown you the string '200' which would have been a clue that your function was not actually returning twiml.

Answer (score 0):

The Twiml you listed seems correct. Is this URL actually valid and the exact same URL being called by your function?

> https://storage.googleapis.com/project_name/folder_name/file_name.mp3

My suggestion is to check the Twilio Console [Error Log](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger) or Call Log to view the actual URL being called by the Twiml. If the URL is invalid or the file is not found, then the Twilio debugger should be showing an error. If there is nothing showing in the Error Log then check the Call Log and view the actual URL being called.

Another possible culprit, is the mp3 of a very high bitrate or not actually an mp3? It could be that Twilio is timing out transcoding your file or having problems with it - those errors should show in the Error Log.

Comment: But the same URL is being played when I pass the URL in Say/Play widget of Twilio.

Comment: What does the Twilio Console Error Log or Call Log show as happening?

Comment: This is the flow status:  https://imgur.com/gallery/8nmycZz , the content type should be Content-Type audio/ulaw, how can i set that?